# Autcomplete using Jquery Ajax in JSP

Tags: json, jsp, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to follow [this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) example
and I have the following in JSP page

```
(getData.jsp)

Department t = new Department ();    
    String query = request.getParameter("q");    
    List<String> tenders = t.getDepartments(query); 

    Iterator<String> iterator = tenders.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String deptName= (String)iterator.next();
        String depto = (String)iterator.next();
        out.println(deptName);
    }
```

How can I use the above to use in Jquery autcomplete? When I tried there was no output coming.

My Jquery autoComplete code

```
 <script>
$(function() {

$( "#dept" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
$.ajax({
url: "getData.jsp",
dataType: "jsonp",
data: {
featureClass: "P",
style: "full",
maxRows: 12,
name_startsWith: request.term
},
success: function( data ) {
response( $.map( data.<??>, function( item ) {
return {
label: item.name + (item.<??> ? ", " + item.<??> : "") + ", " + item.<??>,
value: item.name
}
}));
}
});
},
minLength: 2,
select: function( event, ui ) {
alert(ui.item.label);
}
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your response in JSON format?

Here's what I do when I use Jquery UI Autocomplete:

1. Create a class whose parameters are the ones you will use when you say item.name

   ```
   public string Pam1{ get; set; }

   public string Pam2{ get; set; }

   public string Pam3{ get; set; }


   public SomeResponse(string SomePam)
   {
       // Pam1 = ???
       // Pam2 = ???
       // Pam3 = ??? 
   }
   ```
2. In your handler:

   ```
       context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
       string query = (string)context.Request.QueryString["query"];
       var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

       context.Response.Write(
           json.Serialize(new SomeResponse(query))
       );

       context.Response.Flush();
       context.Response.End();
   ```

**EDIT**

1. The javascript (Here is an example where the user can choose more than one option, separated by coma. If you don't want that, remove it.) txt_autocomplete is the class of the TextBox.

   ```
   $(function () {
       function split(val) {
           return val.split(/,\s*/);
       }

       function extractLast(term) {
           return split(term).pop();
       }

       $(".txt_autocomplete")
       // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
       .bind("keydown", function (event) {
           if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
               $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
               event.preventDefault();
           }
       })
           .autocomplete({
           source: function (request, response) {
               $.getJSON("handlers/autocomplete.ashx?query=" + extractLast(request.term), {
                   term: extractLast(request.term)
               }, response);
           },
           search: function () {
               var term = extractLast(this.value);
               if (term.length < 2) {
                   return false;
               }
           },
           focus: function () {
               return false;
           },
           select: function (event, ui) {
               var terms = split(this.value);
               terms.pop();
               terms.push(ui.item.Pam1);
               terms.push("");
               this.value = terms.join(", ");
               console.log("Pam1 is :" + ui.item.Pam1 + " Pam2 is: " + ui.item.Pam2 + " Pam 3 is : " + ui.item.Pam3);
               return false;
           }
       });
    });
   ```

Comment: enb081 Could you kindly provide some more information about Handler? As here `Request.QueryString["query"];` what exactly is `query`? Where should I do get the database results? Or it should be in `SomeResponse` class? any sample would be of real help. Appreciated.

Comment: Query is the text of the autocomplete textbox. The results will be shown based on the text that the user types. In your ajax request the url can be url: `"getData.jsp?query=" + $('#TextBox1').val();`

Comment: How are the results of the autocomplete based on what the user typed? Is it connected to the database? All this will be handled in the response class, for example  `Pam1 = GetValueFromDataBase(SomeParam)`

Comment: Yes text in autocomplete textbox is based on user typed values. So `Pam1 = GetValueFromDataBase(SomeParam)` will have all the results from database based on parameter text?

Comment: For instance, you have the email of the user typed in the textbox. You make a query where user email is like *'%" + query + "%'*. If you wanna show emails in autocomplete just select emails, amd make Pam1 equal to email, or you can select Username + '<' + email + '>' (gmail-like). In js we wrote  terms.push(ui.item.Pam1); meaning this will appear in the autocomplete terms. The other parameters you may use them for other purposes, for instance the ID of the user with the given email, etc.

Comment: I will try this approach and will definitely get back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am able to reach my Servlet class and it does return response, however nothing gets displayed in textbox. I can see results in firebug console though.

Comment: If you can see the results in console, you can see them wherever you want. Change the line `terms.push(ui.item.Pam1);` to whatever you want, that's what appears in the TextBox. change the Pam1 to whatever parameter you want.

Comment: My problem is it is not reaching to `terms.push(ui.item.Pam1);`

Comment: Then how can you see the results on the console? when you type something, do you get the results?

Comment: I am seeing results in firebug console.

Comment: the results in the firebug console are shown because you have written somewhere console.log, which means the function is working. Check for any small mistake, it must be something really trivial.

Comment: I have managed to resolve the issue, I have added like  `response( $.map( data.department, function( item ) {`. Thanks a lot for your help.